# How to find config files for snap apps?

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, snap

I've recently installed GIMP 2.10 from the Snap Store (which itself appeared somewhat recently in my Ubuntu 16.04 install; I'm pretty sure it wasn't there a while ago).

There are certain things that require putting symlinks in a folder within the GIMP installation structure (specifically, in my case, being able to create from scanner from inside GIMP, rather than scanning to file and then opening the file with GIMP) -- but to do that, I need to know where the Snap install keeps itself.

I gather this might vary from one snap app to another.  At the moment, I need to know this specifically for GIMP 2.10, but if possible, it would be good to know how to find any snap app in order to manipulate config files and such.

Comment: Not sure about snaps, but with debs I have two folders on top level of home folder: `~/.gimp-2.6` and `~/.gimp-2.8`.

Comment: All of the snap settings are stored in `~/snap/` then whatever app it is.  The only issue I see here is that snaps are sandboxed and secured so you will not be able to add directly to the snap app itself.

Comment: @Terrance That looks like an answer -- and it should be.  Comments tend to be deleted over time.

Comment: Converted to an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of the snap settings are stored in `~/snap/` then whatever app it is. Usually the settings are stored in a `current` sub folder that points to the version that is being ran.  Ex.  GIMP is stored in folder `~/snap/gimp/current` which actually points to `~/snap/gimp/252` as it is the current installed version.  In that sub folder you should be able to find the `.config` folder that you can drop in plugins, etc.

One thing to remember is that the actual snaps are sandboxed and secured so you will not be able to add directly to the snap app itself.

Comment: So, developers offering a snap need to package their app differently than they would if it were in a .deb or .rpm?  They need to put things like the folder where you put a shortcut to your scan software outside the sandbox.  I sure hope GIMP 2.10 did this.  I'll check when I'm home.

Comment: @ZeissIkon  I did add one more thing about the `.config` folder in there as well that you should be able to add your plugins, etc into.  But yes, they are different in a way because the sandboxing also makes it so that snaps are limited in what folders of the system they have access to, and normally cannot read through linked folders.  I had that issue with running a Plex server that all my files were not in the home folder so it didn't work the way I needed it to.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: The developers of applications like GIMP do not need to take extra care for snap packages. The software is already configured to use custom locations for the configuration, therefore the snap packages use the feature.

Comment: Right after installing any snap, first thing to check is « does it got the permissions I need ? »

Open « software », installed, search for your gimp. At top of page you'll see a « permissions » button.

Give access to removable-media. Now Gimp can access /media, /mnt and /run/mnt

Beware a snap will never access anything outside of these folders, and never access to hidden files or folders.

See https://snapcraft.io/docs/supported-interfaces