# LibreOffice Writer behaves erratically on KUbuntu

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice

I am running into erratic functionality with LibreOffice writer. It's got to the point where anything beyond a simple few-page document (which could probably be written in Kate!) has become akin to pushing a very large boulder uphill.

The system:

- KUbuntu 22.04
- KDE Plasma 5.24.7
- KDE Frameworks 5.92.0
- Kernels 5.15.0-72-generic (64-bit)
- Graphics X11
- LibreOffice Community 7.3.7.2
- Locale en-NZ
- UI en-US
- Format .odt

The erratic nature comes from the fact that each time I uninstall Writer and reinstall it (in futile attempts to get rid of a problem), a new problem seems to arise.

So:

- modified styles update in the table of content, but NOT in the document
- table of content will not allow styles selection
- will lock up for a while, then carry on working
  Among the most common problems...

I'm just about to pack it all in and go to Scribus.

Has anyone experience such behaviour I wonder?

All help welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using the LibreOffice snap from the snap store?

Comment: @AcceptableName. Thanks for the suggestion. Probably not. I have only done installs/deinstalls using sudo apt. Any reason the snap version might be more reliable?

Comment: I don't think of it as a question about snaps being better. Trying alternatives can be part of troubleshooting.

Comment: @AcceptableName. I see what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: Never seen something similar. First of all delete the folder `$HOME/.config/libreoffice` and test. I have never tried LO snap, but config for those are as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1229135/925128). If that doesn't work, try different versions after removing the one installed, maybe go to libreoffice site and look for those.

Comment: Note that LO can be run as appimage, which is very convenient for troubleshooting because they are official binaries and you can test different versions in parallel. [Here](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/appimage/). Flatpak [here](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/flatpak/). ~ Considering normal apt/deb installation: How come you uninstalled/reinstalled only the Writer? Be sure all LO parts are uninstalled when you do it. You could use Muon instead of Discover to see all details.

Comment: @cipricus. Thanks. There was a big update today from Ubuntu, including L.O. I'll see what happens. If problems persist I'll follow your advice. Installs/uninstalls were done in the console using `sudo apt ...`

Comment: #`Installs/uninstalls were done in the console using sudo apt ...` - I meant: have you done that for `libreoffice` or just the writer (as you suggest, and I have never done.)  #`I'll follow your advice` - first, go to https://www.libreoffice.org/download/appimage/ and test the appimage (no new installation needed, just execute that file). If that works you can use that (it's an official appimage, unlike many of them). If it doesn't, the problem most probably is the user config profile.

Comment: *In fact you don't really clarify in your question if the problem is more than the specific one with styles*. Please clarify. In what way is it "erratic"? What other problems do you have? If you don't, it's not "erratic behavior" but a bug or software limitations and you should file a bug at https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/enter_bug.cgi

Comment: @AcceptableName - Have you used that snap LO? Does it have the full KDE integration the apt version has? (I have tested the appimage and it integrates perfectly.)

Comment: @cipricus TBH, no. I just mentioned it as part of trying alternatives for troubleshooting. I am spending most of my time studying the origin of SunOS as 4.1c BSD has `#ifdef sun` in it.

Comment: Sorry for the absence. :-) I'm very busy at the moment with jobs that need to be done, including the one started in LO.
Since I don't have time to fault-find LO (or whatever is going on) I've moved the project to Scribus. Not a single issue. Yeah. 
Thank you all for your advice.
@cipricus. There were several weird issues. The last I remembered was with the styles.

Comment: I would like to ask you (for when you have the time): is Scribus ok? a complete suite and text editor for work comparable to LO? - I thought it was outdated or just oldish. - Also, I would like to mention two newer office suites that seem rather good (although I prefer LO): [Onlyoffice Desktop Editors](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DesktopEditors) and [FreeOffice TextMaker](https://www.freeoffice.com/en/download). They seem focused on compatibility with MS-office.

Comment: Oh, Sorry, I guess Scribus is for creating pdf files.

Comment: @cipricus. Scribus is a proper desktop publishing program. I wouldn't compare it with LO Writer, which is ... a Word Processor. I have used Scribus before for longish projects (100+ pages) and it doesn't disappoint. Yes its interface could be modernised, but it's so feature-rich and reliable that I have come to ignore the look for what's under the hood. ;-)