# How to remove all snap app's data?

Tags: snap

How to remove all data that is owned by a snap app? The app itself should not be removed, just its data. This is similar to Android's "Clear data" and "Clear cache".

Comment: You can try deleting the configuration files https://askubuntu.com/a/1229135/124466